# Can we retrieve the tag wiki of a synonymized tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

I just realized that [posse](/questions/tagged/posse) was made a synonym of [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up). While I appreciate that (easier to understand), [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up) is missing a tag wiki. So I wanted to copy and modify the one I wrote for [posse](/questions/tagged/posse), but I'm unable to find a way to retrieve it.

Can we retrieve wikis and excerpts from tags which have been deleted or made a synonym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a tag is deleted or merged into another one, the wiki and excerpt are orphaned - but they still exist. Moderators have access to a list of these, so a request should be able to get you links to the revision histories (from which you can copy the markdown):

- [Posse excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99146/revisions)
- [Posse wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/99145/revisions)

Comment: This really should be done automatically.

Comment: What should, exactly? If you *rename* a tag (by merging it into one that doesn't exist), the wiki is copied over automatically; not sure how clever we should get with trying to merge wikis though.